# Error: Non-hexadecimal digit found - brownie

Tags: metamask, contract-deployment, python, error, brownie

When i run brownie run scripts/deploy.py the terminal gives me this error :

```
Brownie v1.16.4 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieSimpleStorageProject is the active project.

Launching 'ganache-cli --port 8545 --gasLimit 12000000 --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --mnemonic brownie'...

Running 'scripts/deploy.py::main'...
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 49, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 103, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File "./scripts/deploy.py", line 10, in main
    deploy_simple_storage()
  File "./scripts/deploy.py", line 5, in deploy_simple_storage
    account = accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])
  File "brownie/network/account.py", line 140, in add
    w3account = web3.eth.account.from_key(private_key)
  File "eth_utils/decorators.py", line 18, in _wrapper
    return self.method(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "eth_account/account.py", line 250, in from_key
    key = self._parsePrivateKey(private_key)
  File "eth_utils/decorators.py", line 18, in _wrapper
    return self.method(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "eth_account/account.py", line 769, in _parsePrivateKey
    return self._keys.PrivateKey(HexBytes(key))
  File "hexbytes/main.py", line 23, in __new__
    bytesval = to_bytes(val)
  File "hexbytes/_utils.py", line 17, in to_bytes
    return hexstr_to_bytes(val)
  File "hexbytes/_utils.py", line 50, in hexstr_to_bytes
    return binascii.unhexlify(ascii_hex)
Error: Non-hexadecimal digit found
Terminating local RPC client...
```

This is my config file :

```
dotenv: .env
wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

my .env file :

```
export PRIVATE_KEY=0x123456abcdef......
```

and my deploy.py file:

```
from brownie import accounts, config


def deploy_simple_storage():
    account = accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])
    print(account)


def main():
    deploy_simple_storage()
```

I discovered that even if i create a new account, when the terminal asks me to enter the private key i get the same error.
Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

After saving your .env file type into console `source .env` that should help.

Also I recommend using this function from Patrick Collins to get your account:

```
 from brownie import (
    network, 
    config, 
    accounts
  ) 



FORKED_LOCAL_ENVIRONMENTS = ["mainnet-fork"]
LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS = ["development", "ganache-local"]


def get_account(index=None, id=None):
    if index:
        return accounts[index]
    if id:
        return accounts.load(id)
    if (
        network.show_active() in LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS
        or network.show_active() in FORKED_LOCAL_ENVIRONMENTS
    ):
        return accounts[0]
    return accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])
```

No matter where you test if on testnet or on local machine it will return the  right account for you.